# How to handle simultaneous transactions in mysql with Java?

Tags: java, mysql, transactions

Have an API that responsible for top-up mobile numbers. To use the top-up API firstly user should register and that stage allocate some credit(BALANCE) to the user.

When make a call to the API with mobile number and top-up amount that amount will subtract from the particular users account balance (Update the balance).

Problem is when a user top-up X mobile and again in the same time Y mobile number.

What are best ways to handle these kind of transaction with JAVA and MySQL(Database).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have different ways to achieve this.

- The easiest one in my opinion is to use optimistic looking: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-optimistic-locking
- Other more complex way is to use Actors. It probably involve a change in the architecture of your app and new frameworks to use but it definitely payoff. An actor receive events (for example, `BalanceUpdate`) and ensures that all messages are processed in order, you can have an Actor per user and the trick is made rooting all the messages related to an user to his actor. Check frameworks like Akka or Vert.X

Comment: Thanx pall very helpful information. Hope to try Pessimistic Locking and Optimistic Locking with my scenario angin thanx.